# "Closest" Quaternion from desired 3D position

Tags: 3d, quaternions

My goal is to find a quaternion, that describes the rotation from an initial orientation (given by a quaternion) to a desired 3D point. The following image shows the set-up:

[image]

The red camera shows the initial orientation `qRed = [1 0 0 0]`, the blue sphere is at position `p = [2 3 1]` and the blue camera is supposed to be oriented such that it faces the blue sphere.

How can I find the quaternion `qBlue` in such a setup?

Comment: What do you mean by **the** quaternion? There are infinitely many ways to rotate the camera so that it faces the blue sphere. After you have found one way, you get the others by spinning the camera about the line connecting the center of the camera and the blue sphere.

Comment: True, I wasn't really clear here. To be more specific, I want to find the "closest" quaternion with respect to the initially given quaternion, such that an interpolation between the two requires minimal rotation in all three axes.

Comment: Sorry about the nitpick. Anyway, one way of finding **a** quaternion is the following. Let $\vec{v}$ be the vector from the camera to the target. Let $\vec{u}$ be the vector the camera is currently pointing at. You will then want to rotate the camera about the axis $\vec{v}\times\vec{u}$. Let $\vec{n}$ be the unit vector pointing in that direction. Then the usual recipe with $q=\cos(\alpha/2)+\sin(\alpha/2)\vec{n}$ should work. Here $\alpha$ is the angle between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$. Caveat: I may have screwed up the sign (IOW to make this work you may need $-\vec{n}$ instead of $\vec{n}$.

Comment: That worked perfectly!